# Joi dependencies error - at least one option must be entered and valid

Tags: reactjs, validation, joi

I would like to do be able to swap between validation and option depending on two different values:

1. If `latitude` is entered it should validate `Joi.date().min(now())`

   1. Set longitude to optional `Joi.date().min(now()).optional();`
2. If `longitude` is entered it should validate `Joi.date().min(now())`

   1. Set longitude to optional `Joi.date().min(now()).optional();`

At least one of these options must be entered. It should be fine if both are entered. I currently get a I get a dependency error when trying to validate of

```
Error: item added into group longitude created a dependencies error
```

With this schema:

```
Joi.object({
  latitude: Joi.number().when('longitude', {
    is: Joi.exist(),
    then: Joi.optional(),
    otherwise: Joi.number().required(),
  }),
  longitude: Joi.number().when('latitude', {
    is: Joi.exist(),
    then: Joi.optional(),
    otherwise: Joi.number().required(),
  }),
});
```

Any help would be really appreciated